# Trying to build regex that I can use to match on nth value

Tags: regex

My string:

```
DATADOG [ALERT:cpu] [VENDOR:rancher-2] [ENV:np] [CLUSTER:local-oma2] [HOST:servername1]
```

My goal:

I'm interested in the value in each one of the brackets. So:

- cpu
- rancher-2
- np
- local-oma2
- servername1

I have a regex that seems to select what I need, but I'm unable to use it to select certain values I want.  The regex is

```
(?<=:).+?(?=])
```

I'd like something like this:

```
(?<=:).+?(?=]){1}
```

that returns `cpu` and

```
(?<=:).+?(?=]){2}
```

that returns `rancher-2` and

```
(?<=:).+?(?=]){3}
```

that returns `np` and so on.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have assumed that one function of the regular expression is to confirm that each matched colon is preceded by a left bracket followed by a word in caps.

You could use the following regular expression to match the text of interest.

```
\[[A-Z]+:\K[^\]]+(?=\])
```

[PCRE demo](https://regex101.com/r/uE0Svo/2/)

The PCRE engine performs the following operations.

```
\[        match '['
[A-Z]+:   match 1+ uppercase letters followed by ':'
\K        forget everything matched so far
[^\]]+    match 1+ chars other than ']'
(?=\])    the following character must be ']'
```

If you want a specific match, such as that following `"ENV:"` in the example, replace `[A-Z]+:` in the regex with `ENV:`.

`\K` resets the starting point of the reported match. It is available in [various languages](https://riptutorial.com/regex/topic/1338/match-reset---k). In addition, it is supported by R's engine (with `perl=TRUE`) and Python's alternative "regex" module.

Some languages that do not support `\K`, do support variable-length lookbehinds (e.g, .NET and Javascript). For those languages the following regex could be used.

```
(?<=\[[A-Z]+:)[^\]]+(?=\])
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/uE0Svo/3/)

Comment: few languages/tools support `\K`

Comment: Thanks so much.  Should have posted here a little bit earlier.  I was also thinking of going with calling out the specific key as a better way to go and thank you.  This worked like a champ \[ALERT:\K[^\]]+(?=\])

Answer (score 1):

To match any (ie all) of them:

```
(?<=:)[^\]]+
```

See [live demo](https://rubular.com/r/T9soJi8qMHJX09).

You can't *just* match the n<sup>th</sup> individually, but you find capture it as group `1`:

```
^(?:[^:]*:){n}([^\]]+)
```

See [live demo](https://rubular.com/r/dRacQ2x7YtJSiM).

where `n` is `1` for `cpu`, `2` for `rancher-2` etc

Comment: This does not check what precedes the colons, but that may not be an issue. The OP did not state that it must be a left bracket followed by a word in caps, as in the example, possibly because that is not a concern.

Answer (score 0):

Simple regex ':(.*?)]'. You can get the list of your desired result.

```
    import re
    s = 'DATADOG [ALERT:cpu] [VENDOR:rancher-2] [ENV:np] [CLUSTER:local-oma2] [HOST:servername1]'
    result = re.findall(':(.*?)]',s)
    print(result)
```

Output:

['cpu', 'rancher-2', 'np', 'local-oma2', 'servername1']

Comment: You might want to strengthen your regex with `'\[[A-Z]+:(.*?)]'`. Also, as there is no Python tag, presenting a Python solution is a limitation. The regex is not fancy, so it is probably supported by most every regex engine, but rounding up the contents of the capture group is a language-specific issue.

Comment: It can be used in any language. I have tried this in javascript and perl too.

Comment: Yes, I agree, if that was not clear from my comment.